# Get all columns of matrix except some indices

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `x` and an index vector `p`. Now I want to select all the columns in `x` **except** the columns in `p`.

Example:

```
x = [12,11,33,33;22,44,33,44;33,22,55,32]
p = [2,4]
```

then it should return

```
out = [12,33;22,33;33,55]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setdiff` and `end`

```
>> x(:,setdiff(1:end,p))
ans =
    12    33
    22    33
    33    55
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
out = x;
out(:,p) = []
```

another way:

```
out = x(:,setxor(p,1:size(x,2)))
%// ore inspired by Mohsen Nosratinia
out = x(:,setxor(p,1:end))
```

and another one:

```
mask(size(x,2)) = 0
mask(p) = 1
out = x(:,~mask)
```

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to do this, but a simple one is:

```
y = x;  %// Create copy of x
y(:,p) = []  %// Remove columns p
```

Or, maybe you prefer to use `sparse`?

```
x(:,~sparse(p,1,1));
```

Or how about `accumarray`?

```
x(:,~accumarray(p.',1))
```

Comment: The first solution was mentioned by @thewaywewalk before you and  `x(:,~sparse(p,1,1))` and `x(:,~accumarray(p.',1))` don't work in general. They work in this case because `p` contains 4 which is the number of columns of `x` otherwise for `p=[2 3]` the result will only contain the first column.